# Pandas - Adding Column to DataFrame, but Items Get Reordered

Tags: pandas, dataframe, etl

I'm trying to simply add a column from another dataframe of the same length using df['columnname'] = df2['columnname'], but the column appears in df with the lines in a different order.

Is there any rhyme or reason to this? Am I doing pandas wrong? Would love any help for this low level data transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is different indices in both Dataframes, you can assign array  or list for avoid it, only necessary same length of both DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'columnname': [5,6,7]}, index=[1,0,2])

df['columnname'] = df2['columnname']
df['columnname1'] = df2['columnname'].to_numpy()
df['columnname2'] = df2['columnname'].to_list()

print (df)
   col  columnname  columnname1  columnname2
0    0           6            5            5
1    1           5            6            6
2    2           7            7            7
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Any documentation that could help me understand why it is reordering without the numpy array step?

I read here, but I don't think I am chain referencing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @Chuck64 - Just looking to pandas documentation, I cannot find this :(

Comment: @Chuck64 - In pandas is called it `alignment` - it means if use `df['columnname'] = df2['columnname']` pandas change order of `df2.index` by `df1.index` , so if difference order is change or added NaNs if not match indices. E.g. `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'columnname': [5,6,7]}, index=[1,0,5])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reindex` to avoid different indexes:

```
df['columnname'] = df2.reindex(df.index)['columnname']
```